# Sibling checkbox condition check

Tags: jquery, html, meteor, siblings

This Meteor template event `click .vote` on the checkbox tries to check it's previous immediate sibling to see if it is checked. How can it be done?  thx

```
Template.checkbox.events({
  'click .valid': () => {
     //do stuff
  },
  'click .vote': () => {  //99c
    //check if its nearest sibiling is checked else exit
    if ($(this).prevAll('input.valid').checked) {  //<------ not cutting it
       console.log('its sibling is checked');
       //do stuff
    } else {
      console.log('its sibling is not checked');
      //do other stuff
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="checkbox">
  <div class="checkbox-container">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label class="check">
        <input class="valid" type="checkbox" name={{name}} value={{value}} checked={{checked}}>{{label}}
        <input class="vote" type="checkbox" name={{name}} value={{value}} checked={{checked}}>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: use `$(this).prevAll('input.valid').is("checked")` also if there is only one use `.prev()` instead of `.prevAll()`

Comment: @guradio That never evaluates to true even if the sibling is checked, so it did not work. And it is the only sibling so I used `.prev()` instead.

Comment: did `.prev()` work? i assume that it is prev based from the html and it should work are you getting error?

Comment: @guradio Using `.prev()` and not getting errors, just the print out to the console confirming the condition is always false.

Comment: I missed putting the `:` because i copied from your code

Comment: Once again, the initial issue is your use of arrow functions where normal functions should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: You can make use of `.siblings()` like below

```js
$(function(){
$(".vote").click(function(){
if($(this).siblings('input.valid').is(":checked")) {  //<------ not cutting it
   console.log('its sibling is checked');
   //do stuff
} else {
  console.log('its sibling is not checked');
  //do other stuff
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <input class="valid" type="checkbox">Checkbox Valid
        <input class="vote" type="checkbox">Checkbox Vote
    </div>
```

For more information on **[Siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**

Comment: This did not evaluate to true even if the sibling is checked.

Comment: I forgot to put `:` before checked, please check updated post

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".vote").change(function() {

  if ($(this).closest('.check').find('input.valid').is(":checked")) { 
    console.log('its sibling is checked');
    //do stuff
  } else {
    console.log('its sibling is not checked');
    //do other stuff
  }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="check">
        <input class="valid" type="checkbox" name={{name}} value={{value}} checked={{checked}}>{{label}}
        <input class="vote" type="checkbox" name={{name}} value={{value}} checked={{checked}}>
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the solution you are looking `:checked`